# Coins and Dice with monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to make a simple "game" using monads
I toss a coin six times and count the number
of heads I see, then I roll a dice;
 if the number of eyes on the dice is greater
than or equal to the number of heads I counted then I win, else I lose

I declared the following types

```
data Coin = H | T
deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum, Ord, Show)

data Dice = D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | D6
deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum, Ord, Show)

data Outcome = Win | Lose
deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

I then go on to define

```
class Monad m => MonadGamble m where
toss :: m Coin
roll :: m Dice
```

Which in my head, when calling toss or roll, should provide a Dice or Coin value, however it does not

Then I try to code the game as follows

```
game = do
        i <- 0
        x <- [toss, toss, toss, toss, toss, toss]
        if x==H
            then do 
                    i <- i+1
                    []
            else []
        y <- roll
        if y > i
            then Win
            else Lose
```

However it is not working, since I am doing something completly wrong in the do block, probably to my lack of understanding of monads
Can anyone offer some advice here?

Comment: Have you implemented an instance of MonadGamble?

Comment: By the looks of it, there is too much to correct here. It seems you are attempting to map imperative programming directly into Haskell, but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I'm not sure you even need a monad. (Except perhaps for randomness.) How about you start by trying to write the function that takes the heads/tails and dice result as inputs and returns whether you won or lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, in Haskell you can't assign variables like `i = i + 1`. In Haskell a variable is always bound to a single value. Symbol `<-` used in the [`do` notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation) always binds a variable to the result of a monadic action, and the monad must be the same throughout the whole `do` block. And every statement in a `do` block must be a monadic action, unless it's a `let` binding. In particular:

```
 -- isn't allowed because 0 is a number, not something of type 'm X':
 i <- 0
 -- isn't allowed because a list is not a monadic action:
 x <- [toss, toss, toss, toss, toss, toss]
 ...
                i <- i+1  -- can't re-assign a variable
                []        -- must be a monadic action, so this must be 'result []'
 ...
    if y > i
        then Win   -- again must be 'return Win'
 ...
```

Furthermore, in `if y > i` you're comparing a number `i` with `y` of type `Dice`, which isn't allowed. Instead I'd suggest you to abandon `Dice` and just let `toss` return a number. A corrected version could look like:

```
import Control.Monad

data Coin = H | T
  deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum, Ord, Show)

data Outcome = Win | Lose
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

class Monad m => MonadGamble m where
    toss :: m Coin
    roll :: Int -> m Int

game :: (MonadGamble m) => m Outcome
game = do
    x <- replicateM 6 toss -- is of type m [Coin]
    let i = length (filter (== H) x)
    y <- roll 6
    if y > i
        then return Win
        else return Lose
```

Note that in order to run `game` you need to write an implementation of `MonadGamble`.

Comment: Nitpicking: "list is not a monadic action". Actually list is a monadic action (just not of the type that matches the rest of the code).

Comment: sequence [toss, ..., toss ] == replicateM 6 toss

Comment: @PedroRodrigues I agree, that's why I wrote _... and the monad must be the same throughout the whole `do` block_,_ but I thought that going into more detail would make things a bit confusing.

Comment: Another nitpick - "i <- i+1  -- can't re-assign a variable". Firstly, `i` is not a variable, strictly speaking - it is a name bound to a value, and the value never varies. But you *can* reassign the *name* `i` to a new value, which shadows the old `i`. For example: `do { x <- return 1; x <- return (x + 1); return x }` is perfectly valid and returns 2. Many people consider shadowing a Bad Thing, but I believe it can be a valid technique for enforcing the fact that an old value should no longer be accessible, especially in the context of monads where destructive updating is possible.